# Extract native xgboost model from H2OXGBoostEstimator model in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o, xgboost

Is it possible to extract native xgboost model pickle file from H2OXGBoostEstimator model in Python and read in by raw XGBoost Python API? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two "h2o-to-xgboost" methods to extract XGBoost hyperparameters and DMatrix from a trained H2O model, that (according to [the docs](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2o.estimators.estimator_base.H2OEstimator.convert_H2OXGBoostParams_2_XGBoostParams)) will give you exactly the same XGBoost native python model.

```
nativeXGBoostParam = h2oModelD.convert_H2OXGBoostParams_2_XGBoostParams()
nativeXGBoostInput = data.convert_H2OFrame_2_DMatrix(myX, y, h2oModelD)
        
nativeModel = xgb.train(dtrain=nativeXGBoostInput,
                        params=nativeXGBoostParam[0],                        
                        num_boost_round=nativeXGBoostParam[1])
```

More info:

- [docs](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2o.estimators.estimator_base.H2OEstimator.convert_H2OXGBoostParams_2_XGBoostParams)
- [example](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/tests/testdir_algos/xgboost/pyunit_PUBDEV_6117_xgboost_compare.py)